# Word Automation Backwards Compatibility With Word 2003

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, office-2003, word-2003

I am working on some Word automation code in C#. I have Word 2007 installed on my own machine (Version 12.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll) but I would like to support Word 2003 as a minimum (Version 11.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll?).

Without having Word 2003 available to me, is there any way that I can target it so that my code is backward compatible? I can't install the PIA redistributable package without having Word 2003 installed.

Comment: Are you thinking that you might be using some features that didn't exist in Word 2003? If so you can just look at the 2003 PIA reference on MSDN and ensure everything you're doing is in there.

Comment: I don't think so but I have managed to test it on a machine that has Word 2003 installed and it doesn't work. I had assumed that was because I am referencing version 12.

Comment: Make sure the v12 PIAs are installed on the test machine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to grab a copy of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll and office.dll from a computer with Word 2003 installed. These are only used to build against so that my code works on systems that have Word 2003. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t mind losing intellisense and you are using .Net 4 you can get rid of the PIA altogether by using dynamic.

Code Example:

```
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
dynamic word = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
word.visible = true;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using .NET 3.5 so don't think this an option. Good to know though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure making a bindingRedirect in app.config will do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll take a look. Thanks.